# JavaScript - How do I get math.random to not randomize same numbers, while using arrays and manually indexed fields?

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Trying to get my lottery machine to **not** randomize same numbers inside my "lottery coupons", but i've ran in to a dead end. What would be the best course here? To use if-else statements, or maybe something else?

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines you want?");

function numbers() {

    var field = [];
    field[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[4] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[5] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';
    field[6] = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1 + ' ';

    field.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    var fieldlength = field.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldlength; i++) {
        document.write(field[i]);
    }
};

for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
numbers(); 
document.write('<br>');
}
```

I've included an image of what the code does at the moment, just to clarify: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqgvzt8n8bjqcsy/example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Use the Fisher–Yates Shuffle to shuffle a set of numbers.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

var ask = prompt("How many lines you want?");

function numbers() {
    var numbers = [];
    for (var i=1; i<40; i++) {
      numbers.push(i);
    }
    numbers = shuffle(numbers);
    var field = [];
    field[0] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[1] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[2] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[3] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[4] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[5] = numbers.pop() + ' ';
    field[6] = numbers.pop() + ' ';

    field.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    var fieldlength = field.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldlength; i++) {
        document.write(field[i]);
    }
};

for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
numbers(); 
document.write('<br>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear and understandable solution, but can you explain what the ".pop()" does?

Comment: It grabs the last element from the array. Just picks the top number and removes it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a seed when generating random numbers preferably the system time in ticks, then modulo it down to you required range. You will still need to regen if a number is already in a row, but your randomness will be better

Answer (score 0):

Here is it a brute-force method. The while loop doesn't have a body, but it won't continue until it find a number which isn't in the array. Note that if generated numbers are more then the range(a.k.a you need to generate 40 unique numbers in the range 0-20) this code will cause an infinity loop. But this is still more effective then most of the methods.

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines you want?");

function numbers() {
    var numbers = 4;
    var nums = [], current;

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        while (nums.indexOf(current = Math.floor(Math.random() * 39)) != -1);
        nums.push(current);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        document.write(nums[i] + ',');
    }
};

for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
    numbers(); 
    document.write('<br>');
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, there's the brute method.